# What is the optimal time to leave a first job?

Tags: software-industry

It is not easy getting a job when all the open positions that are advertised require X number of years experience (usually 2 years from my observation). On the other hand, by staying at my current job I am making much less than if I were to successfully leave for another job. Raises are nothing compared to leaving for higher pay.

When should I leave to optimize pay while still being able to land a new job?

Edit: one day I will ask a good question

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. There's a huge variety of correct answers based on your locale, your tolerance for risk, the rate you learn, the job market, etc. etc. - but in short, as soon as you're able.

Comment: Yoda, this might be more suited for [chat] as you can have a more dynamic discussion and the details of your situation can be more specific. There are normally people in [chat] who are more than willing to discuss questions like this. But something this broad is not a great fit for a question/answer site (feel free to ask in chat and people will help you scope this to be more on topic here, too!).

Comment: If you *are* able to leave for more pay then it seems years of experience isn't material.  However if you don't have the experience necessary to get another job, then you obviously can't move.  I don't see an actual problem to solve.

Comment: 5PM (or whenever your official quitting time is). I know, snarky answer, but I don't think there's a better one. There's nothing wrong with staying at one company forever, if you like what they're giving you to do; there's nothing wrong with moving if you don't.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking at this the wrong way. Your first programming job should be the one where you learn the most. You want to use it to absorb all the knowledge of your colleagues and become a decent programmer in your own right.

As long as you're making enough to live off without getting into debt, try not to think too much about the salary, think about everything else you can gain from the job. Later jobs will pay you more for this knowledge.

In short, move on **when you're not learning very much any more**.

Answer (score 1):

The time to leave is when you have honed your skills well enough that some other company will offer you that job at a higher salary.  This is a supply and demand market, when you have improved yourself and your value well enough you will be able to get the job you are describing.

If you are already motivated to move on, go ahead and start looking for a job.  The market will tell you soon enough how much you are worth.  If you are not getting any interviews, then you (or your resume) are not close to ready for the next level.  If you are getting interviews but no offers, then learn from the interviews what areas you need to improve and work on them.

Without knowing a location, it's hard to know your market for sure.  Many moderately or heavily populated areas have healthy amount of software jobs available, so if you are in one of those areas, the opportunities will be there when you have proven your worth.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've gotten yourself into a bit of a catch-22. Programming jobs only pay well when the programmer achieves a certain set of skills and begins to show value with those skills. Leaving a position because you don't feel you're being paid enough in your own mind isn't going to win you any points with a future employer mostly because it's very likely that it's all in your own mind.

If you want to make more money become good at what you do. In order to become good at what you do, you need to be more concerned with what you do than how much you're making doing it. I like @Fiona's statement about moving on `when you're not learning very much anymore`, but I'd like to take that a step further and add to it: `or if you're providing more value to the company you work for than they're providing you and you can demonstrate it`.